# Surname Validation Code Efficiency - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, while-loop, coding-efficiency

I've written a `while` statement below to validate a surname field and output a boolean value to see if any errors occurred. The program will store all error messages in the variable `errors`. I've added a `break` statement after each error check because I don't want the program to continue checking for errors after one was detected.

I'm not sure if this code is efficient or not - is a `while` statement needed in this case?

What do you think?

```
valcheck = True

# validate surname
while valcheck == True :

    try :
        surname = str(e2.get())
    except :
        errors += "\nSurname not valid - must be a string."      
        valcheck = False
        break

    # check if surname is not empty
    if len(surname) <= 0 :
        errors += "\nSurname cannot be blank."      
        valcheck = False

    # check if surname is alphabetical
    for i in str(surname) :
        # also, allow for hyphens and apostrophes
        if not(i.isalpha() or i == "'" or i == '-') :
            errors += "\nSurname not valid - must be alphabetical."
            valcheck = False

    # if there are no errors, exit the statement
    break
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a `break` at the end, with no `continue`s, so the loop will only ever execute 1 iteration. Seems like a pretty useless `while` statement to me.

Comment: Why do you have the last `break`? If your program will exit no matter an error occurred or not, why not just use a `if` statement?

Comment: When I wrote the code, I wanted it to stop looking for errors after it found one, so I thought a `while` statement would do this easily using `break`. How could I use `if` instead to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Does this seem better?

```
try :
    surname = str(e2.get())

    # check if surname is not empty
    if len(surname) <= 0 :
        errors += "\nSurname cannot be blank."      
    else :
        # check if surname is alphabetical
        for i in str(surname) :
            # also, allow for hyphens and apostrophes
            if not(i.isalpha() or i == "'" or i == '-') :
                errors += "\nSurname not valid - must be alphabetical."

except :
    errors += "\nSurname not valid."
```